# java - building a new array to organize data based off of common index

Tags: java

This is a simple issue I am just having trouble finding the right terms to use for google help. I have some java code that loops some data and I end up having two pieces of information: an `int` id, and an `int` quantity.

However, sometimes the ids are the same, and I want to combine the quantities if they are, rather than having new entries in an array.

In PHP, I would do this as such (assume `$products` is an array with lots of `id`/`quant` data, of course):

```
$newArray = array();
for($products as $id > $quant){
    if(array_key_exists($id, $newArray)){
        $newArray[ $id ] += $quant;
    } else {
        $newArray[ $id ] = $quant;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do this in Java but nothing I find seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [map implementation, like `HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

More or less; adjust types as necessary:

```
Map<Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer>();
for (Product p : products) {
    if (map.hasKey(p.getId()) {
        map.put(p.getId(), map.get(p.getId()) + p.getQuant());
    } else {
        map.put(p.getId(), p.getQuant());
    }
}
```

Slightly cleaner to keep the mainline code readable:

```
// Mainline code
Map<Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer>();
for (Product p : products) {
    putOrAddQuant(map, p);
}

// Extracted helper
public void putOrAddQuant(Map<Integer> map, Product p) {
    if (map.hasKey(p.getId())) {
        map.put(p.getId(), map.get(p.getId()) + p.getQuant());
    } else {
        map.put(p.getId(), p.getQuant());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use HashMap:

```
1. Get the id
2. See if the id is present in the map
3. if not
       insert (id, quantity)
   else (i.e. if present)
       quantity = hashmap.get(id);
       quantity = quantity + new_quantity
       hashmap.put(id, quantity);
```

Helps?

There are many approaches, hashmaps take more memory. You can do this with 2 arrays as well, but then you will spend more time searching through the array.